# How to animate :enter & :leave transitions conditionally in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a list, where the items have an animation like this:

```
<li @animation>
```

And this is my animation trigger:

```
trigger('animation', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ height: '0px', 'padding-top': '0', 'padding-bottom': '0'}),  // initial
    animate('0.5s',
      style({ height: '*', 'padding-top': '*', 'padding-bottom': '*'}))  // final
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    style({ height: '*', 'padding-top': '*', 'padding-bottom': '*', opacity: 1}),  // initial
    animate('0.5s',
      style({ height: '0px', 'padding-top': '0', 'padding-bottom': '0', opacity: 0}))  // final
  ])
])
```

**How can i conditionally turn on/off this animation for a specific item?** Actually i look for sth. like this:

```
<li [@animation]=item.isAnimated>
```

which does not work at all.

And unfortunately Angular documentation has just a sentence about this:

> For elements entering or leaving a page (inserted or removed from the
>   DOM), you can make the animations conditional. For example, use *ngIf
>   with the animation trigger in the HTML template.

But when i combine the animation annotation with a *ngIf, the not-animated items will obviously not be shown at all:

```
<li *ngIf="item.isAnimated" @animation>
```

I want to show all the items further on regardless of isAnimated flag. I just want to turn on/off the animation for a specific item.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [Angular IO](https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger):

When true, the special animation control binding @.disabled binding prevents all animations from rendering. Place the @.disabled binding on an element to disable animations on the element itself, as well as any inner animation triggers within the element.

The following example shows how to use this feature:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
    <div [@.disabled]="isDisabled">
        <div [@childAnimation]="exp"></div>
    </div>
    `,
    animations: [
        trigger("childAnimation", [
            // ...
        ])
    ]
})
class MyComponent {
      isDisabled = true;
  exp = '...';
}
```

When @.disabled is true, it prevents the @childAnimation trigger from animating, along with any inner animations.

Answer (score 5):

#### Create a no-op animation trigger and insert it before `:enter`

I think the `[@.disabled]` approach is fine, but it feels odd to create something and disable it via a different mechanism. Fortunately there's an even simpler way.

---

First, it's important to remember that `:enter` is **exactly** equivalent to `void => *`. In fact here it is in the Angular source code.

```
function parseAnimationAlias(alias: string, errors: string[]): string|TransitionMatcherFn {
  switch (alias) {
    case ':enter':
      return 'void => *';
    case ':leave':
      return '* => void';
    case ':increment':
      return (fromState: any, toState: any): boolean => parseFloat(toState) > parseFloat(fromState);
    case ':decrement':
      return (fromState: any, toState: any): boolean => parseFloat(toState) < parseFloat(fromState);
    default:
      errors.push(`The transition alias value "${alias}" is not supported`);
      return '* => *';
  }
}
```

#### Simplest solution

It's also important to know that Angular's animation engine only matches the **first** trigger and runs it.

Therefore all you need to do is create a new trigger and insert it **before** `:enter`. This animation is a no-op.

```
transition('void => false', []),
transition(':enter', [...])
```

And for `:leave`

```
transition('false => void', []),
transition(':leave', [...])
```

So your animation in the template becomes:

```
[@animation]="enableAnimations"
```

And when it's `false` it'll match and do nothing. ANY other value would match `:enter` which is of course really `void => *`.

The beauty of this is it won't break anything that already uses `[@animation]` because that still matches `void => *` as before.

Note: Any `(done)` handlers will still get executed even after the no-op animation - so if you're using one make sure it does the right thing when there was no animation.

Answer (score 2):

**To clarify:** Angulars **:enter** and **:leave** keywords are to animate components if the are **entering** or **leaving** the dom. Sounds simple but that's exactly the issue with your approach and the aim you try to achieve. Instead of just animating, if there is a new element in the dom you want it more customized, so therefore you need own states, wich can be controlled by yourself in the ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy of a list-entry.

A approach could be the following:

```
@Component({
  animations: [
    trigger('animation', [
      state('invisible', style({ height: '0px', 'padding-top': '0', 'padding-bottom': '0'}),
      state('visible', style({ height: '*', 'padding-top': '*', 'padding-bottom': '*'})
      transition('invisible => visible', animate('0.5s'))
      transition('visible => invisible', animate('0.5s'))
    ])
  ],
})

private readonly isAnimated: boolean = false/true //Where ever you get this value.
public animationState: string //Or Enum with visible/invisible.

public ngOnInit(): void {
  if (this.isAnimated) {
    animationState = 'visible'
  }
}

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
  if (this.isAnimated && this.animationState === 'visible') {
    animationState = 'invisible'
  }
}
```

```
<li [@animation]="animationState"/>
```

*If there are any more questions or issues with this approach - let me know and we can adjust and discuss.*

Comment: the items do not have their own components.. that is why i have to manually build the logic you suggest with ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy.. i would like to wait a bit more if someone has any other idea which works with my current code. Thank you! ;)

Comment: No problem - But if you need individual control's for component it might makes sence instead of using a <li> to make your own small component for this usecase. Nevertheless I am also interested if there is a angular out-of-the-box solution. :)